# Is there a way to implement a horizontal scrollbar within a ttk.Treeview column?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

When the data in a cell exceeds the display width of a Treeview column, it gets cut off and the only way to see it is to resize the columns. Is there a way to have a horizontal scrollbar or panning within a column so you can view the data without resizing columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement a horizontal scrollbar within a ttk.Treeview column?

No, there is not.

The official tcl/tk documentation is very comprehensive. If it's not documented, the widget doesn't support it. You can see the canonical documentation for the treeview widget [on tcl.tk](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm), where you can see there is no support for scrolling a column.